# sending 2 deferent intent's information to the same activity?

Tags: android-intent

I am new in coding and facing this problem since 2 days, I checked many articles and videos before I am asking it here (so I am sorry if there is a similar question here, I never found it)

I am making an app to play songs(for now with no sounds) I have 2 intents going from the ArtistsLlistActivity. both go to the PlyingNowActivity.
so far they are working, if I am clicking on an item in the ArryList, I get my Item showed in the PlayingNow, and if I am Clicking on the 2nd intent, it shows me nothing.
my question :
I want that the 2nd intent sees if the first intent been used before, if yes; then use the last PutExtra been sent from the 1st intent. If no: use no getExtra information.
here are both codes for the Intents I am using;

*1st intent :*

```
artistList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
//                idValue=String.valueOf(id);
                Intent goToPlayNowIntent = new Intent(ArtistsListActivity.this, PlayNowActivity.class);
                goToPlayNowIntent.putExtra("ITEMDATE", artistsNames.get(position));
                goToPlayNowIntent.putExtra("ID", String.valueOf(id));

                startActivity(goToPlayNowIntent);   
               }    
        });
```

*2nd Intent:*

```
final ImageView nowPlaying = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.now_playing);
        nowPlaying.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent nowPlayingIntent = new Intent(ArtistsListActivity.this, PlayNowActivity.class);
                startActivity(nowPlayingIntent);  }

        });
```

*and here is my PlayingNowActivity codes :*

```
package com.example.oaamarasheed.drumcodeplayer;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class PlayNowActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_now);

        int thumb ;
        ImageView artwork = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.artwork);

        String header;
        TextView artistName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_text_view);

        String log;
        TextView songName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.song_text_view);

        Bundle extra=getIntent().getExtras();

        if (extra==null){

            artwork.setImageResource(R.drawable.drumcoderecords);

            artistName.setText("no artist selected");
            songName.setText("now song selected");
        }
        else {
            Intent intent=getIntent();
            CListItems clickedListItem = intent.getParcelableExtra("ITEMDATE");

            thumb = clickedListItem.getThump();
            artwork.setImageResource(thumb);

            header = clickedListItem.getHeader();
            artistName.setText(header);

            log = clickedListItem.getLog();
            songName.setText(log);

        }

    }
}
```

I hope the question is clear and happy to read your help.
happy coding